# Why does the date output look like this?

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand how to convert date to Russian date format. I use SimpleDateFormat,
Date and DateFormat classes to implement this. My code example is below:

```
static void convertToRusDate(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat   simpleDateFormat          = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    Date       date                      = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStr);
    DateFormat russianLanguageDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, new Locale("ru"));
    System.out.println("Date in the Russian language format: " + russianLanguageDateFormat.format(date));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    convertToRusDate("2012-01-31 23:59:59.999+0100");
}
```

I see result like the output below:

```
Date in the Russian language format: 01.02.2012
```

Why does the output look like 01.02.2012 and not like 31.01.2012?

Could you please help?

Thanks,
Alexey

Comment: The `Z` in the format string means "zero offset" from UTC, whereas the input date is in `+0100`, so this is possibly because of the date being converted to a different timezone, **except** you would have to subtract one hour, not add one hour, to convert this time to UTC. So I'm not exactly sure what's happening here.

Comment: Date in the Russian language format: 31 янв. 2012 г. Do you need this ?

Comment: What is your own system timezone?

Comment: @Scratte UTC+03:00

Comment: I figured it was at least UTC+2 :) I used `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` to get a String array (that has a length of 627). I believe the string IDs corresponds to the [list of time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `russianLanguageDateFormat` will display the date in the `Locale` specified. It does not change the timezone that the date is displayed with, which will be your own system timezone by default. I don't have Russian characters on my system's font, so I changed it to `new Locale("en-uk")`. I've also used `getDateTimeInstance` instead of `getDateInstance` so it's clear what's going on.

```java
    DateFormat englishLanguageDateFormat = 
        DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL,
                                       DateFormat.FULL,
                                       // new Locale("ru"));
                                       new Locale("en-uk"));

    System.out.println("Date in the English language format: " +
                         englishLanguageDateFormat.format(date));
```

..will give me:

```java
Date in the English language format: 2012 Jan 31, Tue 23:59:59 Central European Time
```

..because I'm (my system is) at GMT+1, as can be seen by getting the timeZone:

```java
    System.out.println("englishLanguageDateFormat.getTimeZone(): " +
                         englishLanguageDateFormat.getTimeZone());
```

..which prints and corresponds to what my operating system is set to:

```java
englishLanguageDateFormat.getTimeZone(): sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Paris",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=184,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Paris,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
```

You can change the timeZone of the formatted string with

```java
    englishLanguageDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));

    System.out.println("englishLanguageDateFormat.getTimeZone(): " +
                         englishLanguageDateFormat.getTimeZone());

    System.out.println("Date in the English language format: " +
                         englishLanguageDateFormat.format(date));
```

..which will print:

```java
englishLanguageDateFormat.getTimeZone(): sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
Date in the English language format: 2012 Jan 31, Tue 14:59:59 Pacific Standard Time
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. However, I do not favour using the outdated date-time API. You should strive to use the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I agree with you on use of the classes in the time package introduced in Java 8 instead of these old classes. It's just that not everyone is using Java 8 ;)